# How can I capture and rescan TeX source code while preserving synctex data?

Tags: luatex, forward-inverse-search

> **This question led to a new package:**
> [`rescansync`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rescansync)

Let's say I want to replace all `a` (in source code, not rendered output) in a section with `b`...

```latex
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontentsdef}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontentsdefmacro}{\zzz}
abc

abc

abc
\end{filecontentsdefmacro}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\regex_replace_all:nnN {a} {b} \zzz
\ExplSyntaxOff
\filecontentsexec\zzz
\end{document}
```

It works, however the synctex data is lost (it points to the whole block, not individual paragraph/line)

How can I keep the synctex data?

LuaTeX-only solutions are okay.

Comment: I guess it's possible to use one of the set_synctex_* functions in LuaTeX, but the documentation is quite sparse. Or modify the .synctex file after compilation.

Comment: it depends how you define "all". In luatex you could use a lua pattern replace in the `process_input_buffer` callback, but that would change `\makebox` to `\mbkebox` is that OK?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes that's expected...  (for now assume that the *capture*, or somehow getting the whole content in advance is necessary, otherwise process input buffer can do indeed)

Comment: **[[Note]]** I made this into a package https://github.com/user202729/TeXlib/blob/main/rescansync.sty (unfortunately currently there's no documentation&&not on CTAN)

Comment: Note 2. I realize that from Lua it's possible to read the whole file at once... so as long as you don't need to change the *number* of lines you can just read the whole file, process, and return the correct line according to the line number. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641312/lua-approach-for-itemize-fails-if-multiple-lines-are-given-after-item?noredirect=1#comment1598433_641312 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method. For the documentation, see `texdoc luatex` and `texdoc ltluatex` (and the packages being imported).

Disadvantage: it's necessary to write to a real external file (not `\scantokens`)

Search for `!!` in the code for the important parts. (note that `directlua` instead of `luacode*` is used, so be careful with the catcode)

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currfile} % !! need this package for currfilename to be defined
\begin{document}

% write the content to a separate file
\directlua{magic_offset=1 inputlineno_offset=tex.inputlineno+magic_offset} % !!
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{b.tex}
\typeout{1}
abc

abc

abc
\typeout{2}
\end{filecontents*}

% it's also possible to typeset something between the "write" part and the "rescan" part
first line

\directlua{ --[[ !! ]]
saved_synctex_tag=tex.get_synctex_tag()
function handler()
    if token.get_macro("currfilename")=="b.tex" and tex.get_synctex_tag()>0 then
        if not (saved_synctex_tag==nil) then
            tex.set_synctex_tag(saved_synctex_tag)
            saved_synctex_tag=nil
        end
        tex.set_synctex_line(tex.inputlineno+inputlineno_offset)
    end
end
tex.set_synctex_mode(2)
luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer', handler, "synctex patch callback")
}\input{b.tex}\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback('process_input_buffer', "synctex patch callback") tex.set_synctex_mode(0) tex.set_synctex_line(0) }

last line

last line
\end{document}
```

Note that for some weird reason, if `[abspath]` option is provided to `currfile` package the handler will be called several times with `tex.get_synctex_tag()==0`.

Thus the check is added so that it's only called once, but on the actual file.

(I guess that it's because the primitive expand-only the `\input` command or something)

Removing `saved_synctex_tag=nil` line; or the `get_macro("currfilename")=="b.tex"` check will make something worse because
(I think, **not tested**) if b.tex includes e.g. c.tex, then the `set_synctex_line` should not be run for `c.tex`.

Alternative to callback, setting the tag within the input-ed file itself always work.

Comment: **Alternatively**: see [editors - Programmatically editing Synctex files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/423773/250119)  for a method that doesn't require LuaTeX, but needs to call an external program.

Comment: Actually maybe `startfile` callback is more suitable for this.