# synctex using jobname doesn't sync with jobname.pdf

Tags: forward-inverse-search

I have a `.tex` file named `MY_FILE.tex` and a `.pdf` file named `MY_FILE.pdf`.
Now I want to produce a slightly modified version of `MY_FILE.pdf` file using a temp file called `TEMP.tex`.

The only difference between `MY_FILE.tex` and `TEMP.tex` is that a small region is wrapped with `\color{red} text \color{black}`, so that a small portion of text in the new version of `MY_FILE.pdf` is highlighted.

I generate the new versions (a temp version) of the file `MY_FILE.pdf` with the command:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 --jobname=MY_FILE "\input{/tmp/TEMP.tex}"
```

but in this way I loose the synchronization between `MY_FILE.tex` and `MY_FILE.pdf` (forward- and reverse-search).

The command generates a `MY_FILE.synctex.gz` file but the in the second line of the file `MY_FILE.synctex` I read:

```
Input:1:/tmp/TEMP.tex
```

Is it possible to obtain a synchronization between `MY_FILE.tex` and `MY_FILE.pdf` using the technique described above?

Comment: What's the requirement exactly? If you are not limited to do it in TeX you can simply `cp  MY_FILE.tex MY_FILE_BACKUP.tex && cp  TEMP.tex MY_FILE.tex && pdflatex MY_FILE.tex && cp MY_FILE_BACKUP.tex MY_FILE.tex` (bash pseudocode, but might actually be runnable) There are more complex options, see my question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631887/how-can-i-capture-and-rescan-tex-source-code-while-preserving-synctex-data?noredirect=1&lq=1 and the linked once (in particular since this is pdflatex, editing the generated synctex file might be the only option)

Comment: @user202729, indeed I solved editing the generated synctex file. Thanks for the suggestions. If you like you could write your comment as an answer so I can accept it as the solution.