# is it possible to parse the main.synctex.gz by myself

Tags: forward-inverse-search

Now I am genreate the latex synctex file `main.synctex.gz`, is it possible to parse the file by myself? I want to pass the file path\line number\column number, to get the element in which page of pdf, and exactly position of element in pdf. I am using the rust language, and I did not found any package of any languge to parse the `main.synctex.gz` file. I also did not found the standard of `main.synctex.gz`.

why I want to parse the `main.synctex.gz`? because I am working a latex online editor, now everytime compile the latex project, the pdf will locate to the 1st page automatically.

1. I want to remember the page number and the precisely (x,y) of pdf
2. I want to navigate the pdf location from the source editor
3. I still want to locate the source location from pdf viewer

I have searched from internet and found using synctex could do this job: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_to_jump_to_the_source_code_from_the_typeset_PDF_(SyncTeX)

that's why I want to do this job, my backend api was written by rust.

Comment: I don't know how to parse a synctex file, but there are many other ways to exactly position an element in the pdf.  Could you explain a bit more what you're trying to do?

Comment: if you unzip it you'll see it's a simple format with a source file identifier and coordinates in the pdf on each line, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604561/1090

Comment: I have added more background detail info of parse the synctex.gz file.

Comment: the answer expained some key imformation and I am trying to get some clue from there. @AlanMunn